# How to replace cell containing values as 1 and empty cell as 0 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table as follows:

```
Sample    X     Y    Z     P
A        CAT              DOG
B               
C              CAT   TIGER  
D        RAT
```

I want to fill cells with values as 1 and empty cells as 0. and expected output is

```
Sample  X   Y   Z   P
A       1   0   0   1
B       0   0   0   0
C       0   1   1   0
D       1   0   0   0
```

I used

`df.fillna(0)` to fill empty cells with 0. How can I get cells with value as 1?

Comment: can you post the output after doing `df.fillna(0)`.
you can use ```df = df.notna().astype(int)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If empty strings are missing values use [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and convert boolean mask to integers:

```
df = df.notna().astype(int)
```

If empty strings are not missing values use [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for not equal empty string:

```
df = df.ne('').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to fill strings with 1.

```
strings = []
for name in df.columns:
   strings += df[name].unique()

dic_replace_val = {}
for val in strings:
    dic_replace_val[val] = 1 #value that you want to fill

df = df.replace(dic_replace_val)
```